# How can I display AVFrame data of FFmpeg in MFC?

Tags: mfc

Good morning.

Now, H.264 packet is received from the camera with FFMpeg and decoding succeeded.

And I want to output the decoded data to the screen, but it does not work well.
(We successfully saved the decoded data in PPM, Bitmap file, and the screen was well saved.)

Here is the Source code.

CameraStream.cpp

```
void CameraStream::Play(CWnd *view)
{
m_View = view;

m_StreamThread = std::thread{
    [&, this]()
{
    AVPacket packet;

    int i = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> threadMux(this->m_StreamMux);

            if (!m_IsStreamAlive)
            {
                MessageBox(nullptr, _T("ThreadOut"), nullptr, MB_OK);

                break;
            }
        }

        int err = av_read_frame(this->m_FormatContext, &packet);
        if (err < 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (packet.stream_index == m_VideoStreamIdx)
        {
            err = avcodec_send_packet(this->m_VideoCondecContext, &packet);
            if (err < 0
                || err == AVERROR(EAGAIN)
                || err == AVERROR_EOF)
            {
                break;
            }

            CDC *dc = ((CNetworkVideoViewerView*)m_View)->GetDC();

            BYTE *pbmpdata = nullptr;
            BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
            bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -(m_VideoCondecContext->height);
            bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = m_VideoCondecContext->width;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = m_VideoCondecContext->height * m_VideoCondecContext->width * 3;
            HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBSection(dc->GetSafeHdc(), &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&pbmpdata, NULL, 0);

            AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();;
            AVFrame *frameRGB = av_frame_alloc();

            uint8_t *buffer = nullptr;
            int numBytes = 0;

            numBytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(
                AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                this->m_VideoCondecContext->width,
                this->m_VideoCondecContext->height,
                1);

            buffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t));

            int err = av_image_fill_arrays(
                frameRGB->data,
                frameRGB->linesize,
                (uint8_t*)pbmpdata,  // Bitmap Pointer
                //buffer, 
                AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                this->m_VideoCondecContext->width,
                this->m_VideoCondecContext->height,
                1);
            if (err < 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            SwsContext *swsContext = nullptr;
            swsContext = sws_getContext(
                this->m_VideoCondecContext->width,
                this->m_VideoCondecContext->height,
                this->m_VideoCondecContext->pix_fmt,
                this->m_VideoCondecContext->width,
                this->m_VideoCondecContext->height,
                AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                SWS_BICUBIC,
                nullptr,
                nullptr,
                nullptr);
            if (!swsContext)
            {
                return false;
            }

            while (err >= 0)
            {
                err = avcodec_receive_frame(this->m_VideoCondecContext, frame);
                if (err == AVERROR(EAGAIN)
                    || err == AVERROR(EINVAL)
                    || err == AVERROR_EOF)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (frame->pkt_size != 0)
                {
                    sws_scale(
                        swsContext,
                        (const uint8_t * const *)frame->data,
                        frame->linesize,
                        0,
                        this->m_VideoCondecContext->height,
                        frameRGB->data,
                        frameRGB->linesize);

                    // SendMessage Main Thread.
                    ((CNetworkVideoViewerView*)(m_View))->SendMessage(
                        UM_DISPLAYBITMAP,
                        (WPARAM)hbmp);
                }
            }

            av_frame_free(&frame);
            av_frame_free(&frameRGB);

            sws_freeContext(swsContext);
            av_free((void*)buffer);

            ((CNetworkVideoViewerView*)m_View)->ReleaseDC(dc);
        }

        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    };
} };
```

};

NetWorkViewerView.cpp

```
// UM_DISPLAYBITMAP
afx_msg LRESULT CNetworkVideoViewerView::OnUmDisplaybitmap(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    HBITMAP *hBmp = (HBITMAP*)wParam;

    CDC *dc = GetDC();
    CDC memDC;
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(dc);

    BITMAP bmpInfo;
    GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpInfo);

    memDC.SelectObject(hBmp);

    dc->BitBlt(0, 0, bmpInfo.bmWidth, bmpInfo.bmHeight, &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    DeleteObject(hBmp);
    ReleaseDC(dc);

    return 0;    
}
```

The above source runs normally without error, but only the black screen is displayed on the application screen.

Why is it created as a bitmap file but not the bitmap you want to display on the screen?

Thank you in advance.

[ 2018. 01. 10 Solved ]

I modified the source as you suggested, and FFmpeg replaces the buffer space with a bitmap address so the screen looks good.

Of course, there are still some areas that need to be fixed, but the screen looks good. Thank you.

Comment: you have to store the old CDC object (return from memDC.SelectObject(hbmp)) and release it at the end of scope.

Comment: memDC.DeleteDC() is not need here. The destructor form CDC does this already for you at the scope end.

Comment: `OnUmDisplaybitmap` isn't doing anything except create `memdc` with black `hbmp` and blit to screen, it obviously shows up as black. I don't know FFMpeg but `pbmpdata` should probably be assigned to something. Also `GetDC` must be cleaned up with `ReleaseDC(dc)` at the end.

Comment: `bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage` is calculated incorrectly. The width of the bitmap in bytes must be aligned to next DWORD boundary. But you can also just set `biSizeImage` to zero to let Windows calculate it (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx)). You should do more error handling, e. g. check return value of `CreateDIBSection()`. It may fail in case of out of memory or for any other reason. Also you have memory leaks, e. g. `hbmp` and `buffer` are not freed in all code paths and you don't select old bitmap back into `memDC`.

Comment: Don't edit your question in that way. Add a separate answer and check it as answered.